# JQuery not grabbing HTML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML table displayed on my webpage.

```
<div class="timecard">
<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="display_row odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">2400-Orchard</td>
            <td align="right">9:47am</td>
            <td align="right">5/19/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">01:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_even odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">1500-Emerald</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">0:30</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Then I have the following jquery script that grabs the total times for each job_code and adds them up and displays them. However, it does not seem to be working properly. It isn't displaying the totals added up by the jQuery statement underneath the HTML table as it should be.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
var components = timeString.split(':');
var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
total += hrs;

var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function (index, element) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    temp.push(text);
});

// remove duplicates
var job_code = [];
$.each(temp, function (index, element) {
    if ($.inArray(element, job_code) === -1) job_code.push(element);
});

var sum = {};
$.each(job_code, function (index, element) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.job_code:contains(' + element + ')').each(function (key, value) {
        var timeString = $(this).siblings('td.hrs').text();
        var components = timeString.split(':');
        var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
        var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
        total += hrs;
        sum[index] = {
            'job_code': element,
                'total': total
        };
    });
});

console.log(sum);

$.each(sum, function (index, element) {
    $('#total').append('<p>Total for ' + element.job_code + ': ' + element.total + '</p>');
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2D5fb/1/

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: _"it does not seem to be working properly"_ Could you elaborate a wee bit on this?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined "

Comment: Try adding this debugging line: `console.log($(this));` right after the `$(document).ready(function () {` line. I believe `this` in this case is the `window` object. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: Change `var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();` to var `timeString = $(this).siblings('td.hrs').text();`. `.next()` literally only looks at the next element and `td.hrs` isn't the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from `total` not being defined, change:

```
var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
```

to

```
var timeString = $(this).siblings('td.hrs').text();
```

`.next()` literally only looks at the next element and `td.hrs` isn't the next one. `.siblings()` however will run through all the siblings.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7e7Bt/)**

Comment: I agree that code works on jsFiddle, however when I copied it to my site and replaced it with the code I had, it is now displaying now text from the jquery.

Comment: Then you'll need to post a complete code example versus the snippet above. I also don't understand what you mean by "text from the jquery".

Comment: the .append statement from the jquery is not displaying on the webpage, whereas before your changes it was displaying "The total of ...." NaN.

Comment: I made one small change, I don't see how that would do what you're saying. `.next('td.hrs')` to `.siblings('td.hrs')`. What exactly did you change? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console. Here I created a jsFiddle example with my above HTML and your JQuery changes. http://jsfiddle.net/2D5fb/1/

Comment: I changed the code because I agree that your solution should be correct. But it is still not working properly, so there may be another issue.

Comment: Your last fiddle still has `Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined` because you never define total. There's also no element with the ID total in your fiddle.

Comment: My apologies. Forgot to add that when I copied my HTML over. You solution is working now. Thank you for your patience with me as I am just starting to "fiddle" in javascript.